# Set time or sending limit for PHP mailing script

Tags: php, email

I have a simple php registration form that captures a name and email address. After registering, I have a confirmation email set to go to the registrant and one to go to the admin.

I've had an issue where the user only registered once, but some issue caused the email to be sent 50+ times to both the registrant and admin. It's only happened a few times, but I'm trying to prevent it from happening in the future.

I'm thinking of a time limit on running the script, but wondering the best way to handle this. Below is a snippet of the mailing portion of the script.

**2 notes, in case they are of use:**

1. I'm using PEAR Mailer
2. My mail is being sent via MailGun

```
$headers = array ('From' => $from,
    'To' => $to,
    'Bcc' => $bcc,
    'Reply-to' => $email,
    'Subject' => $subject,
    'MIME-Version' => 1,
    'Content-type' => 'text/html;charset=iso-8859-1');

$headers_admin_notification = array ('From' => $from_admin_notification,
    'To' => $to_admin_notification,
    'Subject' => $subject_admin_notification,
    'MIME-Version' => 1,
    'Content-type' => 'text/html;charset=iso-8859-1');

// credentials for SMTP Authentication included from config file

$smtp = Mail::factory('smtp',   array ('host' => 'ssl://smtp.mailgun.org',
    'auth' => true,
    'port' => 465,
    'username' => 'XXXXX',
    'password' => 'XXXXX'));

$mail = $smtp->send($to, $headers, $body);
$mail_admin_notification = $smtp->send($to_admin_notification, $headers_admin_notification, $body_admin_notification);

if (PEAR::isError($mail) || PEAR::isError($mail_admin_notification)) {
    echo("<p>" . $mail->getMessage() . "</p>");
    echo("<p>" . $mail_admin_notification->getMessage() . "</p>");
}
else {
    header("Location: LINK-TO-MY-CONFIRMATION-PAGE?fname=$fname&session=$readable_date_and_time");
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: `but some issue caused the email to be sent 50+ times to both the registrant and admin` best to find and fix this bug than institute a work around where the bug is never addressed knowingly ... could be a bot exploiting your script ... if so you could use session where a flag is checked if the required work has already been performed

Comment: @GetSet thanks for that. I considered the session addition as another option. I can't turn up any reason as to why this occurred, but have reached out to my server provider as well, in case it was something on that end.